# Property of generic type within instance of generic type -- Chaining generic types

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

Sorry, I'm not sure what is the best title for this...

I'm quite new in .NET programming (with a little Java background), and I try to develop a simple typed processing queue.

I puth my object in first ActionQueue. Through internal logic only a single `IAction` in `ActionQueue` processes the object and pushes it in the next `ActionQueue`. Each `ActionQueue` is fueled with `Task` and `BlockingCollection` (but that's not important):

```
Object
...
ActionQueue[IPrepare, IPrepare]
...
ActionQueue[IDownload, IDownload]
...
ActionQueue[ISave]
...
ProcessedObject
```

What I try to achieve is:

- to make `ActionQueue` generic, so only `IActions` of the same sub-interface can be registerred for a job (I use `List<T>` to store actions)
- to have `Next` property to bind the output on `ActionQueue` with input of another `ActionQueue`

Me simplified code looks like that:

```
# SETUP

interface IPrepare: IAction {}
interface IDownload: IAction {}
interface ISave: IAction {}

public interface IActionQueue<in T> where T: IAction {
    IActionQueue<IAction> Next {get;set;} # it can be any action queue
    void Register(T action);
    void Run();
}

class PrepareFromDb : IPrepare {...}
class PrepareFromSettings : IPrepare {...}
class DownloadLocal : IDownload{...}
class DownloadHttp : IDownload{...}
class SaveLocal: ISave {...}

# IN MAIN METHOD

ActionQueue<IPrepare> prepareActions = new ActionQueue<IPrepare>();
prepareActions.Register(new PrepareFromDb(config));
prepareActions.Register(new PrepareFromSettings());

ActionQueue<IDownload> downloadActions = new ActionQueue<IDownload>();
downloadActions.Register(new DownloadLocal());
downloadActions.Register(new DownloadHttp());

ActionQueue<ISave> saveActions = new ActionQueue<ISave>();
saveActions.Register(new SaveLocal(RootPath));

# TRICKY PART THAT FAILS

prepareActions.Next = downloadActions # pass `prepare`d items to `download` queue
downloadActions.Next = saveActions # pass `download`ed items to `save` queue
```

If I declare `IActionQueue` as `interface ITrackQueue<out T> where T: ITrackTransformer` (note **out**), `Main` function shows no error, but  `void Register(T action)` shows error now.

Since it's code for internal library and I'm the only user, I could remove all generic stuff and compile it. But I always try to code as strict as possible.

Or I could use `ActionQueue`'s internal `BlockingCollection` queue as `Next` property, but I don't like leaking internal implementation out, since it breaks incapsulation.

So the question is. What is the most type-safe way to implement this?